# MYSQL unknown column but column exists the varchar is timestamp

Tags: mysql

Here below the code is working

```
 SET @row := 0;
SELECT CONCAT(@row := @row + 1,' ',ui.firstname, ui.mname, ui.lastname) as 'FullName',
d.survey_at_what_blh, ui.status, ui.nature_of_work, ui.level, ui.course_or_section
FROM (select distinct survey_at_what_blh, userid from daily_report) d INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.id
```

but when I add the d.date_opened like this

```
 SET @row := 0;
SELECT CONCAT(@row := @row + 1,' ',ui.firstname, ui.mname, ui.lastname) as 'FullName',
d.survey_at_what_blh, ui.status, ui.nature_of_work, ui.level, ui.course_or_section,  d.date_opened
FROM (select distinct survey_at_what_blh, userid from daily_report) d INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.id
```

its displaying "Unknown Column 'd.date_opened" in 'field list'  but the column does exist
here is the image of my column. Why is it not displaying? Can you guys give me a clue or hint on what i do wrong

[Click this to view my  database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWvmX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss `date_opened` in here:

SET @row := 0;
SELECT CONCAT(@row := @row + 1,' ',ui.firstname, ui.mname, ui.lastname) as 'FullName', d.survey_at_what_blh, ui.status, ui.nature_of_work, ui.level, ui.course_or_section,  d.date_opened
FROM (select distinct survey_at_what_blh, userid, `date_opened` from daily_report) d INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.id

Comment: Thanks bro i didnt think i need it to put inside

Comment: Oh bro sorry i didnt notice when we use date_opened inside there the survey_at_what_blh will not become distinct

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593640/mysql-not-displaying-unique-value-distinct-properly Bro can you take a look at it?