# MYSQL Not Displaying Unique Value (Distinct) Properly

Tags: mysql

Sample data set:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_info;

CREATE TABLE user_info
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,nature_of_work VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,level VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,course_or_section VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO user_info VALUES
(1,'John' ,'Employee'    ,'Call Center','N/A'    ,'N/A'),
(2,'Raul' ,'Grade School','BES'        ,'Grade 6','Nara'),
(3,'Brian','Employee'    ,'BPSU'       ,'2'      ,'BSCS');

DROP TABLE daily_report;
CREATE TABLE daily_report
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
,survey_at_wat_blh VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,date_opened DATETIME NOT NULL
,userid INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO daily_report VALUES
(1,'tor'          ,'2021-03-12 09:54:54',1),
(2,'DFS'          ,'2021-03-12 14:44:06',2),
(3,'DFS'          ,'2021-03-12 10:03:02',2),
(4,'Cupang West'  ,'2021-03-12 10:05:25',3),
(5,'Cupamg Proper','2021-03-12 10:05:59',3);
```

So,

```
SELECT * FROM user_info;
+----+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+
| id | firstname | status       | nature_of_work | level   | course_or_section |
+----+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+
|  1 | John      | Employee     | Call Center    | N/A     | N/A                |
|  2 | Raul      | Grade School | BES            | Grade 6 | Nara               |
|  3 | Brian     | Employee     | BPSU           | 2       | BSCS               |
+----+-----------+--------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+

SELECT * FROM daily_report;
+----+-------------------+---------------------+--------+
| id | survey_at_wat_blh | date_opened         | userid |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | tor               | 2021-03-12 09:54:54 |      1 |
|  2 | DFS               | 2021-03-12 14:44:06 |      2 |
|  3 | DFS               | 2021-03-12 10:03:02 |      2 |
|  4 | Cupang West       | 2021-03-12 10:05:25 |      3 |
|  5 | Cupamg Proper     | 2021-03-12 10:05:59 |      3 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

So here is My Query and its Displaying correct and that is what exactly I want

```
SET @row := 0;
SELECT CONCAT(@row := @row + 1,' ',ui.firstname) AS 'FullName',
       d.survey_at_what_blh AS Place, ui.status, ui.nature_of_work, 
       ui.level, ui.course_or_section
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT survey_at_what_blh , userid FROM daily_report) d 
  JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.id
```

| FullName | Place | Status | nature_of_work | level | course_or_section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 John | Tor | Employee | Call Center | N/A | N/A |
| 2 Raul | DFS | Grade School | BES | Grade 6 | Nara |
| 3 Brian | Cupang Proper | Employee | BPSU | 2 | BSCS |
| 4 Brian | Cupang West | Employee | BPSU | 2 | BSCS |

And when I added the column "d.date_opened"(DateTime Datatype) here what happens the "Place" column  is not going distinct its displaying same value
here is the code where I added the "d.date_opned"

```
SET @row := 0;
SELECT CONCAT(@row := @row + 1,' ',ui.firstname) AS 'FullName',
       d.survey_at_what_blh, ui.status, ui.nature_of_work, ui.level, 
       ui.course_or_section,  date(d.date_opened)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT survey_at_what_blh, date_opened, userid FROM daily_report) d 
INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.id    
WHERE date(d.date_opened) BETWEEN '2021-03-11' AND '2021-03-12'
```

and the result of the above code is this

| FullName | Place | Status | nature_of_work | level | course_or_section | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 John | Tor | Employee | Call Center | N/A | N/A | 2021-03-12 |
| 2 Raul | DFS | Grade School | BES | Grade 6 | Nara | 2021-03-12 |
| 3 Raul | DFS | Grade School | BES | Grade 6 | Nara | 2021-03-12 |
| 3 Brian | Cupang Proper | Employee | BPSU | 2 | BSCS | 2021-03-12 |
| 4 Brian | Cupang West | Employee | BPSU | 2 | BSCS | 2021-03-12 |

so as you can see the 'Place' columns is display the Same Value when I added the d.date_opened. So how do I make it display unique value only? Can you guys give me some tips or hint?

**Here is my Desired Output**

| FullName | Place | Status | nature_of_work | level | course_or_section | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 John | Tor | Employee | Call Center | N/A | N/A | 2021-03-12 |
| 2 Raul | DFS | Grade School | BES | Grade 6 | Nara | 2021-03-12 |
| 3 Brian | Cupang Proper | Employee | BPSU | 2 | BSCS | 2021-03-12 |
| 4 Brian | Cupang West | Employee | BPSU | 2 | BSCS | 2021-03-12 |

Comment: Please include sample input data corresponding to your example above. At any case, you should investigate from what you've change first. Therefore, run the two sub-query with `DISTINCT` each and compare the data it returns.

Comment: you mean my datatable?

Comment: @FaNo_FN Done Bro can you take a look at it

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: @D-Shih  version: 10.4.14-MariaDB

Comment: Just curious: what do you imagine date() does?

Comment: @Strawberry remove the time

Comment: And without an ORDER BY clause, none of this is going to work

Comment: Got it - missed that date_opened had a time element, but note that functions cannot use indexes, so a range comparison would be faster

Comment: if I add the ORDER BY clause the @row will not be in sequence. What should I do?

Comment: Also, I really can't see that '3 Brian' is a useful way to provide information

Comment: What determines the sequence?

Comment: @ The Full Name

Comment: If you don't include the name of the correspondent in the comment, we don't see the comment. So, the user id determines the ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:
**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE user_info
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,nature_of_work VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,level VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,course_or_section VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO user_info VALUES
(1,'John' ,'Employee'    ,'Call Center','N/A'    ,'N/A'),
(2,'Raul' ,'Grade School','BES'        ,'Grade 6','Nara'),
(3,'Brian','Employee'    ,'BPSU'       ,'2'      ,'BSCS');

CREATE TABLE daily_report
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
,survey_at_wat_blh VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,date_opened DATETIME NOT NULL
,userid INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO daily_report VALUES
(1,'tor'          ,'2021-03-12 09:54:54',1),
(2,'DFS'          ,'2021-03-12 14:44:06',2),
(3,'DFS'          ,'2021-03-12 10:03:02',2),
(4,'Cupang West'  ,'2021-03-12 10:05:25',3),
(5,'Cupamg Proper','2021-03-12 10:05:59',3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.id) row_num
     , x.firstname
     , x.survey_at_wat_blh 
     , x.status
     , x.nature_of_work
     , x.level
     , x.course_or_section
     , x.date_opened 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT u.id
                     , u.firstname
                     , r.survey_at_wat_blh 
                     , u.status
                     , u.nature_of_work
                     , u.level
                     , u.course_or_section
                     , DATE(r.date_opened) date_opened 
                  FROM daily_report r
                  JOIN user_info u 
                    ON u.id = r.userid 
                 WHERE r.date_opened >= '2021-03-11 00:00:00' 
                   AND r.date_opened < '2021-03-13 00:00:00'
     ) x
 ORDER
    BY x.id;
```

| row_num | firstname | survey_at_wat_blh | status | nature_of_work | level | course_or_section | date_opened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | tor | Employee | Call Center | N/A | N/A | 2021-03-12 |
| 2 | Raul | DFS | Grade School | BES | Grade 6 | Nara | 2021-03-12 |
| 3 | Brian | Cupang West | Employee | BPSU | 2 | BSCS | 2021-03-12 |
| 4 | Brian | Cupamg Proper | Employee | BPSU | 2 | BSCS | 2021-03-12 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hWVdgeHSYaWuazHMWq5sFD/0)

Comment: i dont understand i recieved an 'Unrecognized token ' on Line 1 to 8 and Line 24 and 25 to my XAMP

Comment: It works in MariaDB too ... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c4443de514e97c2e57439f2f5ebc2011

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XPNK7gXlX4-VzlDtskR4JsNy_EkqDdrv/view?usp=sharing) this is what showing in my XAMP. thanks for the help though